# Creating / Destroying children in view when datacontext property changes using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers

Ok, this is a little hard for me to explain, so Im writing a program using MVVM model with WPF.

I have a grid on my main UserControl which requires the children to be updated (by updated I mean created and destroyed) dynamically through code (as data is changed by the ViewModel I want the children of the Grid to be created and destroyed as needed).

Im pretty sure you cant dynamically create and destroy UIElements using only XAML, so I have  update functions in my view (these update functions ONLY update the UI itself they do not change anything in the ViewModel, so therefore im not breaking MVVM because the code in the view only alters the UI based on the data in the ViewModel, so thats ok right?).

Right now I am assigning the PropertyChanged event of my ViewModel within the View and catching that through code and firing the Update events, so my event in my View class looks like this:

```
        private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "BoardWidth" || e.PropertyName == "BoardHeight")
                RecreateBoard();

            if (e.PropertyName == "Coordinates")
                UpdateCoordinates();

            if (e.PropertyName == "TilesOnly")
            {
                UpdateBoardBlocks();
                UpdateTiles();
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == "BoardBlockViewModels")
                UpdateBoardBlocks();

            if (e.PropertyName == "TileViewModels")
                UpdateTiles();

            if (e.PropertyName == "EntryPoint" | e.PropertyName == "CursorViewModel")
                UpdateEntryPoint();
        }
```

The update events create / destroy children within the main grid of the view using code based on the data in the ViewModel. This current implementation works well.

But, I would like to implement the event handler through XAML. So my question is how do I implement the event handler code above in XAML, I cant find any way of executing a Method within the view when a datacontext property changes. I have looked into DataTriggers but they dont contain the ability to execute the methods. Also the DataTrigger would need to fire when the property changes, not when it is set to a specific value.

I do not wish to push the updates through the ViewModel because this is STICTLY a View thing it has nothing to do with the viewmodel itself. eg. A different implementation of the View may not need to update in these circumstances. Even if I was to pus it through the ViewModel, the view itself would still have the same issue of how to execute the methods.

Thankyou for your help.

Comment: If there is another way of doing this that you think is more correct, please post. :) I should also note, that the boardwidth and boardheight alter the grids columns and rows, how else can this be done through XAML?

Comment: Blend does introduce any dependencies unless you tell it to.

Comment: Ok, thanks, did you mean "doesnt"? I have no idea how to use blend or what is required for the client to use it, but how would I accomplish this through blend anyway?

Comment: Yes, i meant does not, sorry. Blend is just a GUI design tool, it does not really have anything to do with this. Though the libraries (`Interactivity`) that come with blend allow method invocation from XAMl, maybe that is what you meant.

Comment: (By the way, there are quite a lot of useful things in `Interactivity`, like behaviors, and the assembly files are redistributable so this dependency should not me much of an issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you approach may be wrong if you need that much imperative code in your view. In most cases you just bind data to lists and fields etc. You rarely need to create and remove elements, you either have controls autogenerate them (e.g. `ItemsControls`) or you reuse the existing instances.

If you do need to do such dynamic things it might be best to encapsulate that logic in `UserControls` or custom controls, just offering properties that can be bound (internally you can handle the dependency property's value changed event to do any updates).

What is left in the view should be bindings to those controls.

Comment: But if i was to use usercontrols, then that control would have the same problem, how would it dynamically create and destroy ITS child controls. The problem becomes rescursive in nature saying that. To clarify its a scrabble program, and the tiles on the scrabble board need to be dyncamically created and destroyed and put in the correct grid locations, how would I accomplish this without code?

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: Possibly, i for one almost never have code in the view, and if i do it's code to handle view events, not view model events. The control can do that, it just shouldn't be done in your view.

Comment: @HB: But this is not viewmodel is it, it only pertains to creating the UI elements, the viewmodels for those ui elements are created by the main ViewModel and passed to the constructors of the controls.

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: The tiles can be items in a list, you just need to arrange them in a grid, when the list changes the tiles will change. Though you can also work with "static" tiles that just change their state and according to that display the right view.

Comment: @HB: Cheers, i did consider the static way, but thats not really possible either as the board size can change. So the list would be the way to go, but how does the list skip the grid cells which have nothing, does it need to add NULL values or something?

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: I would work with dynamic implicit data templates, you can just add a `UnsetTileViewModel` or something like that to the list and you should get the `UnsetTileView`.

Comment: @HB: Thanks, its different ill give it that, im gonna have to recode the entire thing to implement it this way. Ok so we have determine how it COULD be done, still is it possible do what im asking, or if I want to keep current design do I have to just leave it with the event handler?

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: If you are going to keep the current design i would leave it as is, imperative code (like handling events and calling methods in response) should not be in XAML as i see it, XAML should be as declarative as possible.

Comment: @HB: Excellent, thanks for the great answer, am I necessarily breaking MVVM by having this code in the View (keeping in mind that the View does not create any ViewModels they are created by the  scrabble board ViewModel and then the View passes them to the child View constructors from getting the children ViewModel from its own ViewModel as they are created)? If it is a problem how is it breaking MVVM?

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: Communication is one-directional in any GUI pattern i know, so the View may know the View Model and the View Model may know the Model, i see no problem.